# Is "wannabe" strictly negative?

Tags: meaning

Let's say I want to become social good entrepreneur but I am not there yet. I don't want it to sound up nose and say I am an entrepreneur when I am not so I used this in my social media profile (for instance my SE profile:

> Social Good (wannabe) Entrepreneur

But then I saw [this definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wannabe) of wannabe and it probably means something else than I thought, something way more negative. Or not?

Comment: I'd use 'aspiring entrepreneur'. Wannabe may suggest unprofessional aspirations!!

Comment: *Wannabe* is not a word for a formal register, and it usually has a slightly derogatory implication, such as someone trying to get above themselves.

Comment: Plus you might risk people thinking you used to be in the Spice Girls.

Comment: @Janus Is that a dontwannabe?

Comment: "Wannabe" is often used to emphasize a negative aspect, though the word is really fairly neutral.  But "aspiring" is probably the better choice above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are words with more positive connotations you could use. Try 'budding' or 'aspiring'. Maybe 'neophyte' if you are feeling especially humble.